# extern "C" not working as expected

Tags: c++, extern

I am trying to hook a Win32 API function. I am making a DLL from which I want to export the function, but I am already failing at the basics. My declaration is as follows:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI fnTest(void);
```

but the exported function name is not "fnTest" - as I would expect - but is "_fnTest@0". I can only make it work when declaring the functions calling convention to `__cdecl`, which results to an exported name of "fnTest", but since the Win32 calling conection is `WINAPI/__stdcall` this is not an option.

I am using VS2010. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: i was able to resolve the issue by using the suggested module definiation file. Another method that also worked was using a "#pragma comment(linker, "/export:DirectInput8Create=...") construct.

Answer (score 3):

That mangling is part of the `__stdcall` convention. As the called function has the responsibility to remove the parameters from the stack on return, and removing the wrong amount of data from the stack has disastrous consequences, the number of bytes the parameters take is simply appended to the function name after "@" to let the linker catch potential conflicting definition errors.

Could you explain exactly, how does this pose a problem?

Comment: it is because i want to hook an api call. in my case DirectInput8Create. So the name of "my" function in "my" fake dinput8.dll has to have the same, unmangled name as the original one.

Comment: @Murdock: That's weird. AFAIRC, the API exports are mangled in exactly the same way. WTH is this different with DirectInput? :-/

Comment: its not limited to the directinput call. all functions i export with _stdcall end up mangled (which is correct according to your posting). i have an old borland compiler at work which exports the same declarations unmangled. i think it might be a VS2010 setting.

Answer (score 1):

You should use module definition file (.def) instead of `__declspec(dllexport)`.
Just use the following .def file:

```
EXPORTS
fnTest
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this you will have to [export the functions by ordinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx) rather than by name using a .DEF file.

`stdcall` provides a decoration that describes the length of the parameters, in this case `@0` since you have no parameters.  If you had one parameter it would be `@4`, and so on.